# what is the recommended data type to pass into and out of numba functions?

Tags: python, numba

I was wondering what the recommended data type to pass into and out of numba functions.  In the examples (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/examples.html), I see things like:

```
def create_fractal(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, image, iters):
```

but I typically work with parameter dictionaries, or something like that, which are named.

```
params={'min_x':0,'max_x':100,'arr':rand(5),....}
```

should I use a jitclass?  Something else?  Is there something with a bigger depth than 1?  I guess I'm looking for the equivalent of a c-struct, or what numba would see as a c-struct.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the input side, jitted Numba functions do accept unpacked keyword arguments, and in my limited experience there doesn't seem to be much performance penalty for using them. For instance, if I write

```
@njit
def f(x, y, z):
    return x + y - z

x, y, z = np.ones(100), np.zeros(100), np.full(100, 4.)
vals = {'x': np.ones(100), 'y': np.zeros(100), 'z': np.random.rand(100)}
```

then, after a first run to compile, I get times:

```
In [8]: %timeit f(**vals)
1.41 µs ± 17.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit f(x, y, z)
1.44 µs ± 25.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

My guess is that dicts are your best / most lightweight option here unless maybe you are going to be doing a ton of tiny function calls and the function overhead becomes the main thing.

If you want to output stuff as dicts, and not to convert it yourself, that's a bit trickier, since I don't think that it is supported in nopython mode yet. Maybe at that point the overhead would become substantial enough that jitclasses would make sense.